# Is it considered safe to add the public IP of a host to listen_adresses and the pg_hba file?

Tags: postgresql, network

I have kind of a naive question, but for the moment it's the only way I found to access a local (I mean, located on the host machine) [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org) database from a docker container, so I'm wondering:

is it considered safe or a good practice to add the public IP -- as given by the interface which is used by the computer to connect to the internet, as shown by `ifconfig` ; well actually to my router hereunder but the question may be the same when using a VM or a small remote server open to the world -- of a host to the `listen_adresses` in postgresql.conf file and to add a specific corresponding entry in the pg_hba.conf file?

E.g. with changes as follow in these two configuration files:

[postgresql.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/config-setting.html):

```
listen_addresses = '192.168.xxx.yyy,127.0.0.1'
```

[pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/auth-pg-hba-conf.html):

```
host    all             all             192.168.xxx.yyy/32       scram-sha-256
```

Comment: It is unsafe if you don't take appropriate counter measures, like making sure you have good passwords and that those are needed for logging on, or that your router has a firewall which is working to block incoming traffic.

Comment: Note that `listen_address` is for addresses of network interfaces of your server, whereas in pg_hba.conf you authorize adresses of client hosts. So adding your server address `192.168.xxx.yyy/32` in pg_hba.conf does not allow remote connections, in addition to the fact that all addresses starting with `192.168` are private, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - No.

The Outside World is full of "Ne'er-Do-Wells" that just want to "mess" with anything and everything they kind find *to* mess with.

This is why Web Servers - like Apache - have *so many* defensive tools with which to protect themselves against whatever might be thrown at them.
Simply put, Databases - like PostgreSql - just aren't built that way.

This is why most applications you'll see these days are *layered*, having a client (usually running in a user's web browser), a web server, which can cope with the nefarious "junk" that will get thrown at it and a database, safely nestled away behind protective firewalls and the like and *only* accessed by *trusted* connections, such as that from the web server.